# How to prevent CMake from double compiling sources when bundling static C++ libraries?

Tags: c++, cmake, static

I'm trying to build a static library **libbar** with CMake. **libbar** should contain **libfoo**, i.e. all object files from subdirectory target **libfoo** should appear in **libbar** as well. The simplest dir tree is as follows:

```
bar
├── bar.cpp
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── foo
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── foo.cpp
```

Here is `foo/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(foo)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_library(foo)
target_sources(foo PUBLIC foo.cpp)
```

And here is top `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

project(bar)

add_library(bar)
add_subdirectory(foo)
target_sources(bar PUBLIC bar.cpp)
target_link_libraries(bar PRIVATE foo)
```

In *bar/* I do the following:

```
cmake . -Bbuild
cd build
cmake --build .
```

and I get

```
Scanning dependencies of target foo
[ 20%] Building CXX object foo/CMakeFiles/foo.dir/foo.cpp.o
[ 40%] Linking CXX static library libfoo.a
[ 40%] Built target foo
Scanning dependencies of target bar
[ 60%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/bar.dir/bar.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/bar.dir/foo/foo.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX static library libbar.a
[100%] Built target bar
```

As you can see, file *foo.cpp* was compiled twice, and I'm trying to get rid of this behavior. By the way, this method gives me a correct result:

```
$ ar t libbar.a 
bar.cpp.o
foo.cpp.o
```

If I change PUBLIC into PRIVATE in `foo/CMakeLists.txt`, the build log is as follows:

```
Scanning dependencies of target foo
[ 25%] Building CXX object foo/CMakeFiles/foo.dir/foo.cpp.o
[ 50%] Linking CXX static library libfoo.a
[ 50%] Built target foo
Scanning dependencies of target bar
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/bar.dir/bar.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX static library libbar.a
[100%] Built target bar
```

but foo.cpp.o doesn't get into **libbar**:

```
$ ar t libbar.a 
bar.cpp.o
```

What is the correct way to build **libbar** containing **libfoo** without double compilation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `target_sources(foo PUBLIC foo.cpp)`

This line forces targets that *link to* `foo` to include `foo.cpp` among their sources.

> What is the correct way to build libbar containing libfoo without double compilation?

You have explicitly asked for this, so just... don't:

```
target_sources(foo PRIVATE foo.cpp)
```

- `PUBLIC` means "apply to both self and linkees".
- `PRIVATE` means "apply to self"
- `INTERFACE` means "apply to linkees only"

If you really want `foo.o` to be in both archives (this is dubious) then you could use an `OBJECT` library that both `libbar` and `libfoo` link to.

```
add_library(foo_objs OBJECT foo.cpp)

# later ...
target_link_libraries(foo PRIVATE foo_objs)
# ...
target_link_libraries(bar PRIVATE foo_objs)
```

Comment: The case described in my question is a simplified model of a real one. I have a library, let's call it libfoo, which is used in many projects and pulled as submodule. My colleagues asked me for a single library libbar. I write it highly dependant on libfoo, but they don't need two libraries, so I decided to merge libfoo into libbar. So in my current project I don't need libfoo to be built at all, only libbar that would contain everything. Thank you, I'll check OBJECT libraries.